# Call SmsReceiver from a background service

Tags: android, sms, broadcastreceiver, android-service

I want to ask a question.
I have make a button that starts and stops a background service.
I make a class `SmsReceiver` which reads an incoming sms.
So i want when the service is start to call the the `Sms BroadcastReceiver`.
Any ideas or any other idea how to read an sms with background service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you already have the `SmsReceiver` working fine,all you need to do is register it from the `Service`.To do that you need to override the `Service`'s `onCreate()`.

Your Service should look something like this:

```
public class SmsService extends Service
{
  private SmsReceiver receiver; //global so we can unregister it when the time comes.
  public void onCreate ()
  {
    super.onCreate ();//call to super
    //make a new intent filter so that all incoming SMS get to you as well
    IntentFilter smsFilter = new IntentFilter("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED");
    receiver = new SmsReceiver(); //make a new SmsReceiver
    registerReceiver(receiver, smsFilter); //register the Receiver
  }

  public void onDestroy ()
  {
    unregisterReceiver (receiver); //unregisters the Receiver if Service is killed
    super.onDestroy();
  }
}
```

In the manifest, be sure to include the necessary SMS permissions and remember to also declare the `Service` in the manifest.

```
<service android:name=".SmsService" >
</service>
```

Comment: The service have an error and it wants this code
`code` @Override
 public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  return null;
 }

Comment: Another problem is that if the application is launch without starting the service the broadcast receiver starts to work. any idea?

Comment: For your first comment, yes, you need to override onBind. If you're not going to bind it's fine to leave the implementation as eclipse did it. For your 2nd. Don't declare the receiver in the manifest. Once it's declared in the manifest, the receiver will run add long as some part of your app is running.

Comment: You mean that in the manifest i should not write anything at all for the receiver?

Comment: not even this?
<receiver android:name="com.smsautoreplyandforwarder.SmsReceiver">

Comment: If you only want your receiver to receive while your service is running, yes. The service already registers the receiver, so you shouldn't need a manifest entry for it.

Comment: Thank you now it's working :)
And something last, how can i make this
<intent-filter android:priority="100"> with code at time i create the receiver you show me before?

Comment: Yes. smsFilter.setPriority (100). http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/IntentFilter.html#setPriority%28int%29 Also if this answer has answered your question, feel free to accept it..